# How to bind UserControl dynamically in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently I'm working in a WPF MVVM application,In which I want to display UserControl in MainWindow.xaml using ItemsControl. As Per Requirement I have to switch or Bind Different User Controls by managing some conditions from ViewModel. As i have mentioned in Below code where the UserControl should be bind. But the problem is currently its Static and its Working Perfectly. But I'm not able to Change it per Conditions. So is it anything which can change the UserControlColumn1XL on Runtime from ViewModel? Thanks in Advance.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NormalCollection}" Name="ListNormal" Margin="4,0" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<This below line should be dynamically change through MVVM code>-->
                        <controls:UserControlColumn1XL HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Use a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: can you give me an example or changed code in my above code. I am new in WPF MVVM, could not clear about all things in MVVM.

Comment: DataTemplateSelectors can be a good solution if you have complex view logic, but most of the time you want to select the view based on either the view model type or the value of some property, in which case they're overkill. Check out [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567201/1177147) just the other day.

Comment: @MarkFeldman but in that answer my trigger not working, or on default it will get result, but on changed value its is not triggering, it again bind the same default. Can you help me in that.

Comment: @RahulSaxena answer added.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of using `DataTemplateSelector`....

Here a simple `ViewModel`:

```
public class YourCustomObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string YourProperty { get; set; }  // Remember to rise propertychanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


public class YourViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<YourCustomObject> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

Define the different templates you want to use:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" Name="ListNormal" Margin="4,0">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="firstDataTemplate">
            <UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="otherDataTemplate">
            <UserControl2 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Create a class that inherits from `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
 public class MySelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is YourCustomObject)
        {
            YourCustomObject taskitem = item as YourCustomObject;

            // HERE i'm putting the custom logic for choosing the correct template
            if (taskitem.YourProperty == "Value 1")
                return
                    element.FindResource("firstDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return
                    element.FindResource("otherDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Add an instance of the selector to your main view:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MySelector x:Key="Selector"/>
</Window.Resource>
```

Set `ItemTemplateSelector` property of `ItemsControl` to Selector:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" Name="ListNormal" Margin="4,0" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}">
```

More reference [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The way you usually do this is with DataTemplates. Start with an `ObservableCollection<object> Objects` in your ViewModel...it doesn't have to be `<object>`, it can be some common base class if you like. Then in your XAML you add DataTemplates for each type. I'm placing them in `ItemsControl.Resources` here, but you can put them in `UserControl.Resources` or wherever else you feel is appropriate:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:YourViewModel1}">
            <views:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:YourViewModel2}">
            <views:UserControl2 />
        </DataTemplate>

        ... etc ...
```

Also remove the `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` tag, because if you don't it'll just override the DataTemplates.

That's all you need to do! Every time there's an object of type `YourViewModel1` in `Objects` it'll be displayed with a UserControl1, and the same again for all the other templates you specify.

Comment: what if you have same ViewModel for all UserControls?

Comment: Then you have to use a DataTrigger instead. Again, it's all in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567201/1177147) I posted the other day.

Comment: But trigger is not working. On load its bind default User Control, but again when I changed it, it's not working or triggering the another User Control.

Comment: I can't really help much when you just say "it's not working". The code you posted in your question doesn't contain any DataTriggers. Add them, as I showed in the link, and if it still doesn't work post what you've written here and we can take another look.