# Transfer from one User control to another using EnumVisibilityConverter - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, enums, visibility

When the user presses on a button I want to display a new UserControl. I have created an EnumVisibilityConverter and want to set the enum to display a different user control called login when the button is pressed. So far I have reassigned the enum property to the Login enum type but how can I get this to display the new UserControl

This is the code I have so far:

**EnumToVisibilityConverter**

```
public class EnumToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The converter will return Visibility.Visible if the parameter argument contains a string equal to value, Visible.Collapsed otherwise.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="targetType"></param>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        /// <param name="culture"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // value is null, parameter is null or value is not an enum type
            if(value == null || parameter == null || !(value is Enum))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            string currentState = value.ToString();
            string stateString = parameter.ToString();
            bool found = false;

            foreach(string state in stateString.Split(','))
            {
                found = (currentState == state.Trim());
                if(found)
                    break;
            }

            return found ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;


        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Register.Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <vm:RegisterViewModel x:Key="RegisterViewModelObject" />
        <enum:EnumToVisibilityConverter x:Key="enumToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource LightBlueBrush}"
                Visibility="{Binding CurrentResponse, 
                Converter={StaticResource enumToVisibility}, 
                ConverterParameter='Register'}">

<!-- Move To Login Page -->
        <Button Content="I Already Have An Account"
                Margin="230 0 230 0"          
                Style="{StaticResource ChangeLoginPage}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**ResponseState (Enum Class)**

```
public enum ResponseState
{
    Login,
    Register
}
```

Comment: A converter is overkill for something this simple, you can do it with either a DataTemplate or a DataTrigger. Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567201/1177147) for details.

Comment: Do you want to display a new UserControl within the StackPanel? What happens when you click on the Button?